# How to get the name of a koa route in a pug template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, koa

I named a route using the documentation from here: https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router#named-routes.

Here's the example:

```
publicViewsRouter.get('home', '/', homeView)
```

How can I get the name of the route, which is `home` and put it inside a pug templated page to get the result like this below?

```
<input type="hidden" value="home" />
```